# Classe Java para builder e gerenciamento de dependência

Tags: java

eu tenho projetos usando o gradle como gerenciador de dependência e e build, sei do poder do gradle, mas não o domino, essa questão de ser uma linguagem dinâmica(groovy) força você a saber 100% dos comandos que você digita! Não tem code completion muito menos javaDoc, creio que isso dificulta muito para quem é iniciante na ferramenta, geralmente desenvolvedores Java tem dificuldade inicial, pois é outra forma de "programar".

Por outro lado uma grande vantagem no gradle que vejo é justamente pelo fato de ser linguagem de "script", dessa forma ficamos mais livre para programar, podemos programar no próprio script isso é muito legal, no java não seria possível...

Bem, eu aqui pensando, porque não poderia criar uma classe em Java mesmo que a gente conseguisse gerenciar as dependências do projeto bem como o build?

Veja, não é questão de reinventar a roda, mas é sempre bom pensarmos em alternativas que visa facilitar o nosso trabalho, é assim que as coisas funcionam,se fosse pensar assim(reinventar a roda) estaríamos lá no Ant ainda, nem Maven nem Gradle existiriam.

Perguntas, quais seriam as dificuldades?

O java não é capaz de fazer esse papel?

Já existe ferramenta(ou classe em java) que já faça isso?

Resumindo, do jeito que penso, o "script" seria uma classe instanciada em Java com todas as configurações necessárias do projeto!

Comment: Claro que é possível fazer isso com Java. Ant e Maven são Java, se quiser fazer qualquer coisa programaticamente, basta estudar a API.

Comment: Conhece algum projeto que já faça um wrapper da API do maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É perfeitamente possível fazer isso com Java, exemplos são Ant e Maven.

## Ant

Ant é uma biblioteca para *builds* configurada geralmente a partir de XMLs, mas nada nos impede de executar as *Tasks* diretamente via código Java.

A própria documentação disponibiliza um exemplo: [*Using Apache Ant™ Tasks Outside of Ant*](https://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html)

O exemplo é bem simples, basta estender a *Task* original:

```
static public void unzip(String zipFilepath, String destinationDir) {

    final class Expander extends Expand {
        public Expander() {
        project = new Project();
        project.init();
        taskType = "unzip";
        taskName = "unzip";
        target = new Target();
    }   
    }
    Expander expander = new Expander();
    expander.setSrc(new File(zipfile));
    expander.setDest(new File(destdir));
    expander.execute();
}
```

Eu já brinquei bastante com Ant, criando e estendendo Tasks. Depois que você pega o jeito é bem simples.

## Maven

Não cheguei a fazer esse tipo de "brincadeira" com o Maven, mas aparentemente é bem simples.

Veja o exemplo [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793595/1683070):

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile( new File( "/path/to/pom.xml" ) );
request.setGoals( Collections.singletonList( "install" ) );

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setMavenHome(new File("/usr"));

try
{
  invoker.execute( request );
}
catch (MavenInvocationException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Há também projeto que pode ajudar bastante, chamado [Mojo Executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor). A ideia dele é permitir que um plugin execute outros plugins, mas nada impede que você use-o fora do escopo do Maven.

O maior cuidado que você precisa tomar, para Maven ou para Ant, é que os plugins podem acessar informações de contexto (projeto) e você precisa deixar isso disponível via código.

## Considerações

Na maioria das vezes uma linguagem de programação não faz tanta falta para os *builds*. A parte mais difícil é saber como fazer isso da forma mais direta possível.

Trabalho com o Maven há alguns anos e isso somente foi necessário em casos onde a organização dos projetos era demasiadamente complexa. Porém, o ideal seria reorganizar os projetos. Conhecendo melhor o Maven e como organizar bem os arquivos no projeto precisei cada vez menos de gambiarras nos meus *builds*.

Em alguns casos, é possível mesclar as abordagens declarativa e programática e criar plugins para Ant ou Maven que representam as tarefas específicas de que precisamos.

O problema de usar uma linguagem muito poderosa para tarefas como essa é que seu *build* pode tornar-se tão ou mais complicado de manter do que a própria aplicação em si.

Outra consideração é que a linguagem Java é muito verbosa e pouco flexível, o que a torna não muito adequada para tarefas de automação de *build*. Linguagens de script são mesmo preferíveis para esse tipo de tarefa.

Muitas pessoas fazem isso, mas nem sempre a melhor solução é reescrever a ferramenta na linguagem que você é mais proficiente, ou do jeito que você prefere. Aprender outras formas de trabalhar e programar é difícil, mas depois de algum tempo pode valer a pena.

Não digo para você desistir de tentar fazer algo melhor ou simplesmente reinventar a roda. Mas não perca de vista que muitos dos projetos existentes são feitos por pessoas bastante experientes e você pode aprender bastante com eles.

Comment: "Outra consideração é que a linguagem Java é muito verbosa e pouco flexível, o que a torna não muito adequada para tarefas de automação de build". Falou e disse. Não me vejo trocando DSLs do sbt, Gradle ou Buildr por uso de APIs cruas do Maven / Ant em Java. Prefiro inclusive um XML gigante e opinado como o pom.xml do Maven do que tentar fazer isso pelas APIs. É claro que *code completion* é desejável (e o IntelliJ até faz um bom trabalho com o sbt), mas eu prefiro editar arquivos de build do sbt na mão do que ter que lidar com a verbosidade do Java para uma tarefa dessas.